# Serilog: capture logs conditionally

Tags: serilog

Is there a way to configure Serilog to only capture logs within a 'scope' when a condition is met ?

f.e.:

- I want to capture the logs of a request with minimum level of 'Information' when an Exception occurred. Otherwise do not send the logs to a specific sink
- I want to capture the logs of a request with minimum level of 'Information' when a log with level 'Error' or higher has been logged. Otherwise do not send the logs to a specific sink.

or:

- Capture the logs to a specific sink when some flag is set in code at runtime:

```
using var scope = _logger.CreateScope(//enable or disable a specific sink for this scope)
_logger.LogInformation("...");
...
```

Comment: See https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1646
Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59822584/is-there-a-serilog-equivalent-of-log4nets-bufferingforwardingappender-for-detai